# Declaration of beans and Dao classes in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Spring give the facility of defining beans class and DAO classes in application-context.xml file right now i am defining the bean classes like that

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.forum.jsfbeans" />
```

But many places in google i saw people defined DAO,beans,Service classes differently something like this

```
<!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <bean id="User" class="com.otv.model.User"/>

    <!-- User Service Declaration -->
    <bean id="UserService" class="com.otv.user.service.UserService">
        <property name="userDAO" ref="UserDAO" />
    </bean>

    <!-- User DAO Declaration -->
    <bean id="UserDAO" class="com.otv.user.dao.UserDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

we have to defined all the classes in `application-context.xml` file differently(like i did above) or we can just use the below tag for each type of classes not a matter its DAO,Bean or Service?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.forum.dao,com.forum.jsfbeans,com.forum.service" />
```

If we will defined something like above it will work and Spring know what action it have to perform in DAO,Service or Bean classes .

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DavidWallace we have to defined all the classes in application-context.xml file differently(like i did above) or we can just use the below tag for each type of classes not a matter its DAO,Bean or Service?

Answer (score 0):

It's just two different ways to achieve the same result. Some people prefer beans to be defined in xml others like autodetection with component-scan.

Comment: It will effect the Performance if we are using 'component-scan'